# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ ... Reason: no suitable image found. updated device to latest update 13.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, xcode10.3

I have just updated my testing device from 13.1.2 to latest update  13.3.1. (before the update in 13.1.2 app was ran in the device without any error). Now I got the project to build, but after the launch screen I get an error saying:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/demo.app/test demo
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE997A49-F99F-42B0-BBF8-FDC1FF967F84/test demo.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/AWSCognito: stat() failed with errno=1
Message from debugger: failed to send the k packet
```

I have tried following solutions

> clean, build and then run the project. did not Work for me.

Clean and reinstall pods

> 

Delete derived data and reinstall pods

still properly working (without any error prompting in later version 13.1.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Cocoapods you can **remove or comment by #** `use_frameworks!` from your Podfile and reinstall it, that should fix the issue for now. dont forget to **clean build folder** before you run the app on update 13.3.1 device.

Answer (score 3):

Select the target in which this framework is embedded and go to the **General** tab than under **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content** your Framework that is giving this error should be listed and select the option **Embed & Sign**. This only works on main targets though not if you embedded a framework in another framework.